# CSS Border Won't Completely Wrap Text

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've been trying to put a border around a specific piece of text on my website in CSS, but it won't completely wrap around it.

Here's what I'm talking about:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdIwb.png)

And here's the code that I used:

`.box-outline {
 border: 4pm solid black;
 border-radius: 4px;
}`

For context, I'm using a WordPress theme and trying to put a border around that piece of text on my navigation menu. WordPress gives the option to style menus entries by putting in the CSS [class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKwVa.png) but it's not working correctly. Is it my theme that's screwing me over, or is there something I can change?

Comment: Show your HTML, ideally in snippet that reproduces the problem, otherwise we won't be able to help. It looks like it's inside a container which doesn't allow overflow, but I can't give any detail without seeing more.

Comment: +1 for a full example. at a guess it's an issue with your width/box-model setting, try setting the box-model to border-box. Or it could be an issue with a overflow property somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.box-outline {
 border: 4pm solid black;
 border-radius: 4px;
 z-index: 100500;
}
```

Maybe there is some another element, that closes your right border... z-index may help.

Or... it seems, you've set incorrect width to your last div/button, or the width of div, that contains all buttons.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, Optimus, and everyone else that commented. Z-Index didn't change anything, the border is still not closing. But I really think that may be due to the theme, and I don't have enough knowledge to assist the people helping me or help myself. I've switched to a different WordPress theme (the border works now); the other one wasn't too customisable anyway. Thanks again!